# Oracle - Filtrar por data

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma coluna `dt_atualiza_log` que está com o tipo `DATE` na tabela (é salvo no formato 01/12/2011 10:10:48)

Não estou conseguindo filtrar no `and` da minha *query*. Já tentei de várias formas, a última:

```
AND ma.dt_atualiza_log >= to_date('01/01/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi')
```

> Erro: ORA-01830: a imagem do formato da data termina antes de
>   converter a string de entrada inteira

Parece que estou errando na hora mesmo. Podem ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Funcionou... Mas o dado na tabela tem hora, exemplo: 08/01/2018 21:40:13. Isso não é relevante?

Comment: vai ser se a comparação for menor, `'01/01/2000 08:00:00' <= '01/01/2000'` essa comparação retorna falso, nesses casos, ou você tira a hora da coluna, ou adiciona um dia no parâmetro: `< '02/01/2000'` vai retornar tudo até `01/01/2000 23:59:59`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Erro diz que o formato informado (DD/MM/YYYY) acaba antes de converter a string de entrada, porque no formato não tem hora e no parâmetro informado tem.

Então só tirar o horário (00:00:00):

```
AND ma.dt_atualiza_log >= to_date('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')
```